# MySQL PDO safely delete row in table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

If I understood this correctly, then this would be the way to safely replace a row in a table:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("REPLACE INTO MyTable(ColA,ColB) VALUES(:ColA,:ColB)");
$stmt->execute(array(':ColA' => $colA, ':ColB' => $colB));
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

But how would I safely delete a row? (Only by knowing the ColA value)

Comment: What do you mean by 'safely'? What's not safe about using the same logic of your code for a `DELETE`?

Comment: I don't really know tbh, I just heard that people can easily get into my server when I do anything wrong. The values $colA and $colB are user inputs btw. How would my "logic" look in PDO for delete anyway? I only know: "DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `ColA` = '$colA'"

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it right by using PDO and prepared statements - this is the safe route to executing queries. The same logic can be used for a delete:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ColA = :ColA");
$stmt->execute(array(':ColA' => $colA));
```

Prepared statements can (and should) be used for any type of query, whether `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `REPLACE`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, etc... The 'prepared' magic to it is the separation between the query itself and the values of the parameters you are using. `:ColA` is a placeholder that you will replace when executing the query - in this case by using the array with the placeholder name and the value to use in its place - `array(':ColA'=>$colA)`. This is the safe way to execute queries because it prevents parameters (user input) from being misinterpreted as `SQL` commands, and thus minimizing the risk of malicious queries being executed on your server.

In short, you're doing it right.

Comment: Nice explanation however real statement parameter values aren't so much *"replaced"* as *"bound"*. Think of it like function / method arguments; the prepared statement is the function and the parameters the arguments.

Comment: @Phil Yeah, as I was writing that I felt like 'replace' wasn't the most accurate way to describe it, but thought it was enough for conceptualization - you're absolutely right, though, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Use a prepared statement in exactly the same way as you have for the `REPLACE` query

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ColA = ?');
$stmt->execute([$colA]);
```

or, if you're really sold on named parameters...

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ColA = :ColA');
$stmt->execute([':ColA' => $colA]);
```

Comment: my editor give me an error unless i write: `$stmt->execute(array(':ColA' => $ColA));` instead of `$stmt->execute([':ColA' => $colA]);` is my editor just stupid?

Comment: The `['key'=>'val']` syntax came about in PHP 5.4 - you are probably using an older version of PHP

Comment: Square brackets were addedin PHP 5.4, your editor may not know about the new notation.

Comment: @Barmar *"new"* being a very subjective term in this case ([PHP 5.4 released 2012-03-01](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0)